urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>
I`m using some code, which takes a segmented story, and sends the parts to chatgpt for sentiment analysis and should store it in a cvs afterwards. It uses the OpenAI package, but since I have to use Python 2.7 (I cannot upgrade), I had to adjust the code to the python 2.7 syntax.
When I run the code I get this error: urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>
The error occurs in the do_open-method in urllib2.py :
def do_open(self, http_class, req):
        """Return an addinfourl object for the request, using http_class.

        http_class must implement the HTTPConnection API from httplib.
        The addinfourl return value is a file-like object.  It also
        has methods and attributes including:
            - info(): return a mimetools.Message object for the headers
            - geturl(): return the original request URL
            - code: HTTP status code
        """
        host = req.get_host()
        if not host:
            raise URLError('no host given')

        h = http_class(host, timeout=req.timeout) # will parse host:port
        h.set_debuglevel(self._debuglevel)

        headers = dict(req.unredirected_hdrs)
        headers.update(dict((k, v) for k, v in req.headers.items()
                            if k not in headers))

        # We want to make an HTTP/1.1 request, but the addinfourl
        # class isn't prepared to deal with a persistent connection.
        # It will try to read all remaining data from the socket,
        # which will block while the server waits for the next request.
        # So make sure the connection gets closed after the (only)
        # request.
        headers["Connection"] = "close"
        headers = dict(
            (name.title(), val) for name, val in headers.items())

        if req._tunnel_host:
            tunnel_headers = {}
            proxy_auth_hdr = "Proxy-Authorization"
            if proxy_auth_hdr in headers:
                tunnel_headers[proxy_auth_hdr] = headers[proxy_auth_hdr]
                # Proxy-Authorization should not be sent to origin
                # server.
                del headers[proxy_auth_hdr]
            h.set_tunnel(req._tunnel_host, headers=tunnel_headers)

        try:
            h.request(req.get_method(), req.get_selector(), req.data, headers)
        except socket.error, err: # XXX what error?
            h.close()
            raise URLError(err)
        else:
            try:
                r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)
            except TypeError: # buffering kw not supported
                r = h.getresponse()

        # Pick apart the HTTPResponse object to get the addinfourl
        # object initialized properly.

        # Wrap the HTTPResponse object in socket's file object adapter
        # for Windows.  That adapter calls recv(), so delegate recv()
        # to read().  This weird wrapping allows the returned object to
        # have readline() and readlines() methods.

        # XXX It might be better to extract the read buffering code
        # out of socket._fileobject() and into a base class.

        r.recv = r.read
        fp = socket._fileobject(r, close=True)

        resp = addinfourl(fp, r.msg, req.get_full_url())
        resp.code = r.status
        resp.msg = r.reason
        return resp

According to the variables the host is {str}'api.example.com'
Is this correct? Or should it be something else? Maybe I broke it by changing the code?
Im really new and I dont know how to handle this at all, thanks for any answers and help!!!
When i do urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com") I don´t get an error, and my internet connection works fine. I also restarted my PC :)
